# Passing the LoadResult object (DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.ResponseModel) from the API and its deserialization on the client side

Tags: c#, json-deserialization, devextreme

I would like to get LoadResult (DevExtreme.AspNet.Data.ResponseModel)  object from API and use it (after deserializing) on the client side.

In API server i have method that return:

```
return Ok(DataSourceLoader.Load(items.Select(item => new FormattedItem(item, project, serialNumberFormatter, diagnosticNumberFormatter)
                        {
                            DirectItemLink = _itemLinkBuilder.Build(item, projectId, itemId),
                            DocumentLink = _itemDocumentLinkBuilder.Build(item),
                            CanEdit = _permissionService.CanEdit(item, userId),
                            ShowHistoryPopups = isHistoryEnabled
                        }), loadOptions));
```

On the client side i getting this object by:

```
var apiClient = new HttpClient();
var apiResponse = await apiClient.GetAsync(url);
string json = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But when i try deserialize json to object

```
LoadResult items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoadResult>(json);
```

i have error

> Cannot create and populate list type System.Collections.IEnumerable. Path 'data', line 1, position 9.

How can I do this?

Best regards.

Comment: Show your `LoadResult` class. Likely the property `data` is an `IEnumerable`. `IEnummerable` is not a type, it's an interface. You need a concrete type like `List`.

Comment: var Result = await Server.GetUsers();

var j = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Result.Data);
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(j);

This is one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with below code.

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await Client.GetAsync(string.Format(Options.Value.Routes.UserDeviceRoute.GetGridData, loadOptions), cancellationToken);

        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);

        dynamic dynamicResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseContent);
        LoadResult loadResult = new LoadResult()
        {
            totalCount = dynamicResponse.totalCount,
            groupCount = dynamicResponse.groupCount,
            summary = dynamicResponse.summary
        };

        loadResult.data = dynamicResponse.data.ToObject<List<UserDeviceGetResponse>>();
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?